# Scrapy crawler - set up dedicated cache DNS server?

Tags: python, dns, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy recommends setting up a dedicated cached DNS server on its website for a broad crawl (crawling millions of pages from many websites)

Since i'm using a rotating ip/proxy -> every request is routed through a different ip address

i assume DNS lookups would be going through different IP addresses as well

Would it still make sense to setup a dedicated cached DNS service?